# load another javascript library and script on click event?

Tags: jquery, onclick, click

Either it is possible to load another JavaScript library and function on the click event of jquery?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(function($) {
            jQuery('#maincontent').on('click', '.mainlisting-div  a', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var link = $(this).attr('href');

                $('#ajaxcontent').fadeOut(500, function() {
                    // here i am wanted to load another library and function

                    $(this).load(link + ' #ajaxcontent', function() {


                    });
                });
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You don't need jQuery(document).ready(function() { jQuery(function() { // code here } }); as they both do the same thing. $(function() { // code here }); is all you need. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[$.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)**:

```
$.getScript( "your script url here",function() {
    // Callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate the DOM adding a  tag like this:

```
$("script").attr("src", "path").appendTo("body")
```

Not tested but it should work because the script is parsed when it is added to the DOM.